# How to change the webgui password in pfsense from a console?

Tags: networking, firewall, freebsd, pfsense, console

Is there any way to change the password of the web GUI administrator user in pfSense from the console?

Just to mention I didn't lock myself out from the web GUI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the way to change the password for a user from a console/ssh of a pfSense.

Fist you have to download the change admin script to your /etc/phpshellsessions with the following command > fetch -o /etc/phpshellsessions/ https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pfsense/pfsense/c07e853bb4a67a3b728b7546b36801eaef770c19/etc/phpshellsessions/changepassword

And then you run the the following: pfSsh.php playback changepassword  , it will ask you the new password and to confirm the new password for the user.

After you complete the above you can try log in the webgui with the new password.

Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

Please check https://doc.pfsense.org/index.php/I_locked_myself_out_of_the_WebGUI,_help!
Bottom line:

- restart
- pick option 4 from the menu
- when prompted to start /bin/sh -> hit enter
- remount hdd

  /sbin/mount -o rw /
- reset passwd

  /etc/rc.initial.password

Comment: Thank you for your answer but i didn't locked out my self. I just want to find a way to change my webgui admin password from the console and not accessing the Web interface.

Comment: Then I guess that you need only the last step. And a reboot.

Comment: When you run the last command /etc/rc.initial.password it just reset password to 'pfsense' so you can access the webgui and change it from there. I want to change the password from the console without need of accessing the web interface.